# Parse JSONObject

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have the following JSONObject:

```
{"Questions":
        "{Question5=[Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4], Question4=[Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4], Question3=[Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4], Question2=[Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4], Question1=[Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4]}"
}
```

I am really new at working with JSON. What I need is array of JSON objects, each key is Question5, Question4 etc. and the values to be the answers. Can you help?

Comment: Have you looked at [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)?

Comment: Go to json.org to learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  But note that if you dump Maps & Lists, or the Map/List equivalent objects used by some JSON APIs, they may not display (in `println` via `toString()`) exactly like the JSON source.

Comment: But it does look suspiciously like your "Questions" string is really just a String, and not JSON.

Answer (score -1):

you need to parse it. i recommend [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library to do so.
but as i see your string is NOT JSON. json should be `key : value` and not `key=value` as your string

Comment: well I used JSONObject(map) to create it